# Undefined method for nil:NilClass in JRuby

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am developing a framework to integrate scripting languages in java. For Ruby, I am using JRuby (last  9.4.5.0 version).

I have the following Java interfaces:

```
public interface ContextListener {
   public void init(ScriptContext context);
}
```

and

```
public interface Script {
   public int execute();
}
```

and

```
public class APIHelper {
   public int getValue() {
      return 10;
   }
}
```

and

```
public class ScriptContext {
   Map<String, Object> additionalHelpers = new HashMap<>();

   public ScriptContext() {
       this.additionalHelpers.put("api", new APIHelper());
   }

   public Object getAdditionalHelper(String name) {
      return additionalHelpers.get(name);
   }
}
```

My Ruby script is:

```
require 'java'
java_import 'org.scripthelper.context.ScriptContext'
java_import 'org.scripthelper.context.ScriptHelper'
java_import 'org.scripthelper.context.ContextListener'
java_import 'org.scripthelper.ruby.addhelpers.APIHelper'
class ScriptClass
java_implements 'org.scripthelper.context.ContextListener', 'org.scripthelper.ruby.addhelpers.Script'
    attr_reader :context
    attr_reader :api
    def init(ctx)
       context = ctx
       obj = ctx.getHelper("api")
       @api = obj.to_java(Java::org::scripthelper::ruby::addhelpers::APIHelper)
    end
  def execute()
    a = @api.getValue()
    return a + 1
  end
end
```

The context returns Object elements. The `init` method is called before the `execute` method. I did:

When I try to evaluate the `execute` method, I have the following exception:

```
org.jruby.exceptions.NoMethodError: (NoMethodError) undefined method `getValue' for nil:NilClass
```

I thought I correctly made the cast to a `APIHelper` interface, which has the `getValue()` method. What did I do wrong?

For information, this older version of the script (without casting) evaluated correctly and returned a correct result:

```
require 'java'
java_import 'org.scripthelper.context.ScriptContext'
java_import 'org.scripthelper.context.ScriptHelper'
java_import 'org.scripthelper.context.ContextListener'
class ScriptClass
java_implements 'org.scripthelper.context.ContextListener', 'org.scripthelper.ruby.addhelpers.Script'
    attr_reader :context
    def init(ctx)
       context = ctx
    end
  def execute()
    a = 1
    return a + 1
  end
end
```

Comment: I am not familiar with JRuby but in ruby you would define `initialize` rather than `init`, so maybe try changing `init` to `initialize` in your ruby script

Comment: I used the same method name before, and I had no problem. I will show the previous example of the scripty which worked correctly.

Comment: Can you also post the actual code that is causing the issue, e.g. *"The init method is called before the execute method. I did:"* (what follows "I did:..."). Your error is caused by `@api` being `nil`, all instance variables that are not "set" will be `nil`. Without JRuby I can reproduce your issue easily with `ScriptClass.new(ctx).execute` becuase `init` never happens in this process.

Comment: You are right, I will post it

Comment: Your "old" code works because `init` does not matter and `execute` does not reference an instance variable change `init` to `initialize` and then try again.

Comment: I have a case where I used a result returned by the context class which worked (in my case, I returned a File name), I will reorganize my problem presentation to clarify everything, and give a complete reproductible case (using JRuby because I think that it is related to the  Java to Ruby integration)

Comment: Before you go through all of that just try my suggestion, I bet you it will solve your issue.

Comment: I don't see in your code that you veryify that @api has received a non-nil value during the execution of `init`. I would do a `p @api.class` after the assignment.

Comment: JRuby is, at the end of the day, a Ruby. Ruby initialiser is named `initialize`, not `init`. Try this: `class Foo; def init; p "INIT" end end; Foo.new` and you should not get `INIT` printed. Now try `class Bar; def initialize; p "INIT" end end; Bar.new`.

Answer (score 0):

Does your work if you just get rid of the `.to_java` call and simply set `@api = ctx.getHelper("api")`?

Remember that Ruby is a dynamically typed language, so Ruby variables don't have static types and you can always call any method on an object that it responds to.

---

In Java, variables and method arguments have static types, and the Java compiler will not let you call a method on an object unless it can tell by its static type that the method should actually be there (or unless you force it with an explicit type cast).  So in Java, while you can assign an APIHelper instance to a variable of type Object (since every non-primitive type in Java is a subclass of Object), you can't actually call any APIHelper methods on that Object variable unless you first explicitly cast it back to the APIHelper type (possibly raising a ClassCastException if it's not actually an APIHelper instance).

In Ruby variables have no static type.  When you try to call a method on an object, the Ruby interpreter checks *at runtime* if that object responds to that method and will either invoke the method or raise a NoMethodError if it doesn't.  (Actually, before raising an error, it'll first try calling [`method_missing`](https://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/method_missing) on the object just in case it might be able to handle the call after all!)  In Java terms, you can *sort of* think of this like the interpreter always automatically casting every object to its most specific possible type.

Of course, in Java you can emulate this kind of dynamic method lookup and casting using [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful), and indeed that's exactly what JRuby does under the hood when you call a method on a Java object.

(It actually does [a lot more than that](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby), including translating between Ruby and Java method naming conventions and allowing you to reopen a Java class in Ruby and add Ruby methods to it or even inject entire Ruby modules into the Java class.  Of course such modifications will only be visible on the Ruby side of things, since they're only modifying the Ruby wrapper for the Java class.)

---

Anyway, the take-home message here is that you basically *never* need to call `to_java` in JRuby, except in one specific case: when calling a polymorphic Java method that behaves differently depending on the type of its arguments, sometimes you need to explicitly tell JRuby which Java type the argument should be cast to if the method call would otherwise be ambiguous.  Using `to_java` can help there, although in those cases [`java_send`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#calling-masked-or-unreachable-java-methods-with-java_send) is often better.

(Also, [arrays](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#arrays) in JRuby have a special implementation of `to_java` that converts the elements, which can sometimes be useful.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way even you can load "jar" in CLASSPATH:

```
require 'java'

class ScriptClass

     def load_jar
       # Location to have you JAR where ScriptContext,ScriptHelper,ContextListener & APIHelper class exist
       @jar_lib = your.base_path + 'lib' 
       # Now require all your jar
       require @jar_lib + jar1
       require @jar_lib + jar2
       ...
       
       if RUBY_PLATFORM == "java"  
          java_import 'org.scripthelper.context.ScriptContext'
          java_import 'org.scripthelper.context.ScriptHelper'
          java_import 'org.scripthelper.context.ContextListener'
          java_import 'org.scripthelper.ruby.addhelpers.APIHelper'
        end
     end
       
    attr_reader :context
    
    def initialize(ctx)
      load_jar
      context = ctx
    end
    
    def execute()
      a = 1
      return a + 1
    end
end
```